# Advice: Implementation of SlidingMenu on Android (J. Feinstein)

Tags: android, android-sliding

I have a problem *(seriously, I do not know how to do it :D)* with the implementation of SlidingMenu library (from Jeremy Feinstein... link is dowm) for Android. Is there anyone who can help me with implementation process? I am beginning Android programmer, so sometimes I need help :)

**Library - https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I used Feinstein library myself and decided to create example app with flexible and reusable implementation as much as I could think.

Please check [the source code at GitHub](https://github.com/baruckis/Android-SlidingMenuImplementation).

[Download app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baruckis.SlidingMenuImplementation) directly to the device to try.

Here sliding menu, as it's content, uses list fragment. I made two approaches. One, when list data is filled with data loaded from XML file. Second, when data is filled from separate class.

I added many comments to catch the idea more easily. I hope it will be helpful! ;)

Comment: @Andrius Baruckis Hey, I used your sample project, its simple and good :) But I am facing a problem in the source code. The following import is not found: import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

Comment: Ok fixed this one xD But having error at getSlidingMenu() Error is: The method getSlidingMenu() from the type SlidingMenuInitialiser refers to the missing type SlidingMenu

Comment: Ok fixed all bugs XD I just removed ur import statement and changed to  original Feinstein library :D

Answer (score 10):

Create an `Activity` which extends `SlidingActivity`, create a `Fragment` for your menu and in  the method `onCreate` add this :

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
frameLayout.setId(ID_MENUFRAME);
setBehindContentView(frameLayout);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
ft.replace(ID_MENUFRAME, menuFragment);
ft.commit();
```

where ID_MENUFRAME is an int which is not an id present in your layout (I set it to 1).
Then, if you want to open or close the menu, call :

```
getSlidingMenu().toggle();
```

And you use your activity like any other activity.
Note that you will have to customize your `SlidingMenu` programmatically. For example :

```
sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingMenu_behindOffset);
sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingMenu_shadowWidth);
sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
```

Comment: **Thank you very much!** I hope this will definitely help me ;-)

Comment: I hit errors here: "MenuFragment" cannot be resolved to a type. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to create your own `Fragment` and replace `MenuFragment` by your own fragment.

Answer (score 5):

There's an example project in there: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/example

Just import it to Eclipse.